# Hold key down gets interrupted after ~2 seconds

Tags: keyboard, ps2-keyboard

I've just bought a new (cheap) PS/2 keyboard.

When I hold a key down it get's interrupted after approximately 2 seconds.  This is frustrating on games where things like holding a key down makes you run or shoot etc.  After 2 seconds the running / shooting stops, and I have to release the key and press it down again.

It's consistently 2 seconds when I test via, Alt + tab.  (The selection gets "selected" without me releasing the Alt key after ~2 seconds).

Although the keyboard is PS/2 I've got it connected through USB via a splitter.  It's the only thing connected to the splitter however, as the mouse is in the PC's actual PS/2 slot.

Could the splitter be the problem or is it the keyboard?  I've checked keyboard settings but there's very little there - nothing related to this.  The driver is up-to-date apparently (although it is 2006).

Is this just an intended feature?

Comment: The easiest way to test this is to remove the splitter, attaching the keyboard to the computer directly. If it's not that, then it's the keyboard. (Though I've always used <$20 keyboards and haven't seen this issue before.)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 - I'll try removing the splitter later and see if it's that.